# How to fix "An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor()' on type 'RedisCacheService"

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am going to change my server, but when I want to run my application on the new server, I get this error:

> An exception was thrown while activating Walrus.AAA.Services.SharedServices.Core.TokenService -> Walrus.AAA.Services.EndUserServices.Core.UserService -> Walrus.AAA.Services.SharedServices.Core.CacheService.RedisCacheService. Inner: An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor()' on type 'RedisCacheService'.

This application still works correctly on the previous server, but it gives this error on the new server.
Does anyone know what I should do?

I checked the connection between this server and Redis and it was correct. The config file related to this connection is also correct .

Comment: Can you please share the details of the exception as in what was the exception thrown.

Answer (score 0):

(I know this relates to StackExchange.Redis because if receiving the same question via two other routes!)

We can't comment on `RedisCacheService` without seeing `RedisCacheService` which is not a StackExchange.Redis type. However, generalizing: consider looking at the `.InnerException` of this exception to see if this sheds some light on the underlying problem. If that doesn't help, but the error is definitely in a "connect" step: the `ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect[Async](...)` API accepts an optional "log" parameter; if you pass in a suitable writer, lots of additional context is emitted, which can help identify what is failing.